# NullPointerException at mocked class method

Tags: java, testing, mockito

I am currently writing a test for the method buy of the class Buy which should actually test if the correct request is going to the server and if it's handling the response correctly.

At the moment I always receive a java.lang.NullPointerException because execute(post) returns null instead of the CloseableHttpResponse.

> CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);

But I don't understand because in my test I tell mockito to return the mocked closeableHttpResponse.

The test

```
  @Test
    public void testBid() throws IOException {
        //given:
        HttpPost post = mock(HttpPost.class);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = mock(HttpResponse.class);

        StatusLine statusLine = mock(StatusLine.class);

        ObserverImp observer = mock(ObserverImp.class);

        CloseableHttpClient closeableHttpClient = mock(CloseableHttpClient.class);
        CloseableHttpResponse closeableHttpResponse = mock(CloseableHttpResponse.class);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = mock(HttpEntity.class);
        BufferedInputStream inputStream = mock(BufferedInputStream.class);

        //and:
        when(statusLine.getStatusCode()).thenReturn(200);
        when(httpResponse.getStatusLine()).thenReturn(statusLine);
        when(closeableHttpClient.execute(post)).thenReturn(closeableHttpResponse);
        when(closeableHttpResponse.getEntity()).thenReturn(httpEntity);
        when(httpEntity.getContent()).thenReturn(inputStream);
        when(inputStream.read()).thenReturn(1);
        when(observer.getKey()).thenReturn("##213");


        Buy buy = new Buy(observer, closeableHttpClient);
        buy.bid(14455);
    }
```

And the related **Implementation**

```
public class Buy {
    private ObserverImp observer;
    private CloseableHttpClient httpClient;

    public Buy (ObserverImp observer, CloseableHttpClient httpClient) {
       this.observer = observer;
       this.httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    public void buy(double price) {
            String queryArgs = "command=order&amount=1" + "&price=" + String.valueOf(price); // generates query

            HttpPost post = new HttpPost("wwww.hm.edu/projectGroup1");
            post.addHeader("Key", observer.getKey());
            try {
                post.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(queryArgs.getBytes("UTF-8")));
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                System.out.println("Exception in run");
            }
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<>();

            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("command", "order"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("amount", "1"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price", String.valueOf(price)));
            try {
                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
                CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                Scanner in = new Scanner(entity.getContent());
                String orderNumber = "";
                while (in.hasNext()) {
                    orderNumber = in.nextLine();
                }
                String[] findOrderNumber = orderNumber.split(".");
                long lastOrderNumber = -1;
                try {
                    lastOrderNumber = Long.valueOf(findOrderNumber[3]);
                } catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
                    System.out.println("NumberFormatException");
                } finally {
                    if (lastOrderNumber != -1) {
                        observer.setOrderNumber(lastOrderNumber);
                    }
                }
                in.close();
                EntityUtils.consume(entity);
                httpClient.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Exception occured during process");
            }
        }
}
```

Please help me to fix that issue. Thank you a lot.

Comment: Mocks return `null` by default. You should set them up properly if you expect anything else.

Comment: There are lot of issues in your test code. To begin with this statement  
`HttpClients.createDefault` cannot be mocked using mockito. You need powermock to do so

Comment: Yes, you haven't mock this line `CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();`

Comment: sorry I had the wrong version of the class in my clipboard. I fixed it. Do I still have to powermock the createDefault method of HttpClients with the code above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need that:

> when(closeableHttpClient.execute(any(HttpPost.class))).thenReturn(closeableHttpResponse);

Your code before just waits for the exact post (equals) that you created in your test. But your buy method produces another post. Thats why your execute(post) cannot match the class. any() solves that

Comment: It worked! Thank you for your explanation. It makes sense :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the return type, by default null will be returned from the mock. Also in the implementation call createDefault http object.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought this is returning the concrete type?: 
when(closeableHttpClient.execute(post)).thenReturn(closeableHttpResponse);

Comment: No, you are checking there if `closeableHttpClient` gets a specific `post` object (your mock), but actually, it will get this one: `HttpPost post = new HttpPost("wwww.hm.edu/projectGroup1");`